# Upgrade to Drupal 9 from8 having Twig related error

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-9

I recently upgrade drupal to 9 versions via composer. And i am getting following error in drush watchdog:show command

```
Error: Class 'Twig_Function_Function' not found in  
Drupal\bookmark_field\TwigExtension\BookmarkExtension->getFunctions()
```

Comment: I haven't been able to find bookmark_field. Is that a custom module?

Comment: yes it's custom module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Twig_Function_Function` is a [deprecated](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/deprecated.html#functions) class from Twig 1, the use of which was [deprecated in Drupal 8](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21twig%21twig%21lib%21Twig%21Function%21Function.php/class/Twig_Function_Function/8.9.x) and has now been removed as [Drupal 9 requires Twig 2](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/how-to-prepare-your-drupal-7-or-8-site-for-drupal-9/preparing-for-use-of-twig).

In your bookmark_field module, you need to update the code to use [`\Twig\TwigFunction`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21twig%21twig%21src%21TwigFunction.php/class/TwigFunction/9.0.x) instead of the old `Twig_Function_Function`.